# Exact string replacement in php

Tags: php, string, replace

I'm looking for a way to replace a string in php that exactly matches with the subject.

For example I got a file named 'hello-world.txt' having three lines:

```
'http://www.example.com/'
'http://www.example.com/category/'
'http://www.example.com/tag/name/'
```

and I need to replace the `'http://www.example.com/'` with `'http://www.example2.com'`

```
$string=file_get_contents('hello-world.txt');
$string=str_replace('http://www.example.com/','http://www.example2.com',$string);
echo $string;
```

I will be getting a result similar to this:

```
'http://www.example2.com/'
'http://www.example2.com/category/'
'http://www.example2.com/tag/name/'
```

But What I actually need is something like this:

```
'http://www.example2.com/'
'http://www.example.com/category/'
'http://www.example.com/tag/name/'
```

Please Help!!!!

Comment: How are the strings separated?

Comment: I've tested the code you've posted and it seems to work fine.  The only issue I found is you left out a / in your second argument to str_replace, which will make it output: http://www.example2.com 
http://www.example2.comcategory/ 
http://www.example2.comtag/name/

Comment: Hmm... it seems that the text has been edited somewhat.  Some clarification please, does OP need only the first value replaced as it currently says or is it only replacing the first value and he needs them all replaced as I originally remember it saying?

Comment: Hi,Got the solution from codaddict $string=preg_replace('~^http://www\.example\.com/$~m','http://www.example2.com',$string);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `preg_replace` with the `m` modifier as:

```
$string=preg_replace('~^http://www\.example\.com/$~m','http://www.example2.com',$string);
```

[**Code In Action**](http://www.ideone.com/VEckO)

Answer (score 0):

First check if the current line is what you're looking for. If not, just spit it back out.

Answer (score 0):

Either `$string=str_replace("'http://www.example.com/'", "'http://www.example2.com'", $string);` since in your example you have single quotes around each line or use preg_replace like this:

```
$string=preg_replace('/^http:\/\/www\.example\.com\/$/', 'http://www.example2.com/', $string);
```

... if those single quotes aren't supposed to be there. The $ at the end of the regex means the end of the line and the ^ means the beginning of the line. Periods and / need to be escaped hence the \. and \/

I haven't tested this code.  Here is a link to preg_replace() http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php